# dlang std.concurrency support for foreign host processes

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, d, rpc

I'm not sure whether this question belongs on StackOverflow, or somewhere else.  Feel free to suggest a different location.

D's std.concurrency package is described here: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_concurrency.html.  I've duplicated the relevant text here (emphasis mine).

> This is a low-level messaging API upon which more structured or
>   restrictive APIs may be built. The general idea is that every
>   messageable entity is represented by a common handle type (called a
>   Cid in this implementation), which allows messages to be sent to
>   **in-process threads, on-host processes, and foreign-host processes**
>   using the same interface. This is an important aspect of scalability
>   because it allows the components of a program to be spread across
>   available resources with few to no changes to the actual
>   implementation.
>
> Right now, **only in-process threads are supported** and referenced by a
>   more specialized handle called a Tid. It is effectively a subclass of
>   Cid, with additional features specific to in-process messaging.

Does anyone know of any efforts to implement the foreign-host component of this framework?

Comment: Related: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/Re_What_would_you_do..._-_Extending_std.concurrency_151275.html